# WinSCP error code 4 when uploading large file

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp, winscp

I'm trying to move a file from my local machine to another machine into which I've SFTP-ed.

The file has 160MB. The transfer stops after a quarter of the file is moved over, with the following message:

> Copying files to remote side failed
>   General Failure(server should provide error description)
>   Error code: 4
>   Error message from server: Failure

Comment: *"server should provide error description"*

Answer (score 1):

This may be because space is full on your server.
Try executing df -Th command to see.
Free space on your server and try again it works.

Answer (score 0):

This would typically be due to a full file system on the server or exceeded user quota.

Actually a complete error message suggests that:

> Common reasons for the Error code 4 are:
>
> - Renaming a file to a name of already existing file.
> - Creating a directory that already exists.
> - Moving a remote file to a different filesystem (HDD).
> - **Uploading a file to a full filesystem (HDD).**
> - **Exceeding a user disk quota.**

For details, see also WinSCP documentation on the [SFTP code 4](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/sftp_codes#code_4).